voice prompted tChatGPT query not querying
I am trying to build a python script that takes voice commands and sends it to chatGPT API and says back the response. Ultimately, I want to use this script for a rasberrypi to create an AI voice assistant.
Here is my script:
import speech_recognition as sr
from gtts import gTTS
import playsound
import openai

openai.api_key = "sk-proj-uKtP3PAVekIYMq5Hi0t1T3BlbkFJuWfUlMyjzLp3ZrKlOkf4"

messages = [{"role": "system", "content": "You are a kind helpful assistant."}]

def recognize_speech():
    recognizer = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening...")
        recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
        audio = recognizer.listen(source)

    try:
        print("Recognizing...")
        query = recognizer.recognize_google(audio)
        print("You said:", query)
        return query.lower()
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print("Could not understand audio")
        return ""
    except sr.RequestError as e:
        print("Could not request results; {0}".format(e))
        return ""

def query_chatbot(query):
    global messages
    if query:
        messages.append({"role": "user", "content": query})
        
        response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
            model="gpt-3.5-turbo", 
            messages=messages,
            max_tokens=150
        )
        
        reply = response['choices'][0]['message']['content']
        
        messages.append({"role": "assistant", "content": reply})
        
        return reply
    else:
        return ""



def speak(text):
    tts = gTTS(text=text, lang='en')
    tts.save("response.mp3")
    playsound.playsound("response.mp3")
    os.remove("response.mp3")

def main():
    while True:
        print("Listening for 'hey chat'...")
        trigger_word = recognize_speech()
        if "hey chat" in trigger_word:
            print("Activation word detected.")
            query = recognize_speech()
            if query:
                response = query_chatbot(query)
                print("Response:", response)  
                speak(response)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


And here is my terminal:
PS C:\Users\Joe Blanshan\Desktop\starship AI code> & "C:/Users/Joe Blanshan/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/python.exe" "c:/Users/Joe Blanshan/Desktop/starship AI code/voice_chat.py"
Listening for 'hey chat'...
Listening...
Recognizing...
You said: hey chat
Activation word detected.
Listening...
Recognizing...
You said: who is the world record holder in the mile
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Joe Blanshan\Desktop\starship AI code\voice_chat.py", line 69, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\Users\Joe Blanshan\Desktop\starship AI code\voice_chat.py", line 64, in main
    response = query_chatbot(query)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\Joe Blanshan\Desktop\starship AI code\voice_chat.py", line 34, in query_chatbot
    response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Joe Blanshan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\openai\lib\_old_api.py", line 39, in __call__ 
    raise APIRemovedInV1(symbol=self._symbol)
openai.lib._old_api.APIRemovedInV1:

You tried to access openai.ChatCompletion, but this is no longer supported in openai>=1.0.0 - see the README at https://github.com/openai/openai-python for the API.

You can run `openai migrate` to automatically upgrade your codebase to use the 1.0.0 interface.

Alternatively, you can pin your installation to the old version, e.g. `pip install openai==0.28`

A detailed migration guide is available here: https://github.com/openai/openai-python/discussions/742

PS C:\Users\Joe Blanshan\Desktop\starship AI code>

I am sort of new to coding. I am not very sure how to use the API for openai, nor access it. I am expecting to talk into the mic after it recognizes the trigger phrase and then receive a voice output of chatgpts response.
